# Can't find my home folder

Tags: 14.04, bashrc

I am sure the question is stupid but I am very new to linux (I am on ubuntu 14.04 in a persistent USB key). 
I need to edit my .bashrc and .zshrc file to install linuxbrew but I just don't find where it is in the graphical interface. When I do a `ls -a` in the terminal (home/myname) I see that the .bashrc is here, but I'd like to edit it outside the terminal, directly in the graphical interface (is it possible ?). I can't find my "home/myname" folder in Files app.

Comment: There is a button labelled "Home" on the top of the Places bar at the left. To see files which have names beginning with a period press Ctrl-H (for "hidden").

Comment: Open `terminal`, type `gedit .bashrc` and `gedit .zshrc`. Be careful, 'cause if you mess these up, you may have trouble logging in. And why must these files be modified to do an **install**? Your home folder is at `/home/myname`, not `home/myname`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is usually a way, depending on the file manager you are using, to have it show the hidden files.  You can use CTRL-h, or select "View->Show Hidden Files" in most file managers.

That being said, even if your file requester or manager doesn't have that capability, you can always still specify the filename directly on the command line. For example, if you are using the xed text editor, then the command line in a terminal window...

```
$ xed ~/.bashrc
```

...will load up your .bashrc file in the editor.